# ssh key authenticated user unable to use apt-get update

Tags: authentication, ssh, key, chmod, chown

**Ubuntu Linux 16.04.5**

I have configured a server for SSH Keys Authentication With PuTTY.
Key authentication works fine for the user account accessing the server, the problem is that when attempting to utilize "***apt-get update***" the system returns:

```
tornado@freeradius:~$ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

I have seen on multiple posts to similar topics that the solution is the use "***sudo apt-get update***" - the issue with this is the user "tornado" has no password.

Additionally, I have configured "***sshd_config***":

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

The user "***tornado***" was created using "***adduser tornado --disabled-password***" option, so when attempting to "***sudo apt-get update***" I am prompted for the user "tornado's" non-existent password.

The permission of "***home/tornado***" was changed to 755 which made no change with the issue at hand, so I reverted the *CHMOD*.

"***stat /home/tornado***" output

```
  File: '/home/tornado'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 19267592    Links: 4
Access: (2700/drwx--S---)  Uid: ( 1000/ tornado)   Gid: ( 1000/ tornado)
Access: 2018-09-14 11:28:01.035536814 -0700
Modify: 2018-09-14 10:50:00.864863347 -0700
Change: 2018-09-14 11:33:13.685020607 -0700
 Birth: -
```

"***stat /home/tornado/.ssh***" output

```
  File: '/home/tornado/.ssh'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 19267599    Links: 2
Access: (2700/drwx--S---)  Uid: ( 1000/ tornado)   Gid: ( 1000/ tornado)
Access: 2018-09-14 11:28:01.035536814 -0700
Modify: 2018-09-14 10:44:34.251451611 -0700
Change: 2018-09-14 11:28:01.035536814 -0700
 Birth: -
```

"***stat /home/tornado/authorized_keys***" output

```
  File: '/home/tornado/.ssh/authorized_keys'
  Size: 209             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 19267590    Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/ tornado)   Gid: ( 1000/ tornado)
Access: 2018-09-14 11:33:41.053150514 -0700
Modify: 2018-09-14 10:44:34.127451092 -0700
Change: 2018-09-14 11:28:01.035536814 -0700
 Birth: -
```

**Root privileges to the user "*tornado*" were granted as well ...**

```
visudo
```

**added:**

```
# User privilege specification
tornado ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I also attempted: "chown tornado:root /home/tornado"
which made no change to the situation.

---

## Solved

A password was added to the user "*tornado*" which allows me to sudo into the root user which provides functionality.